# how can I add another language choice to bootstrap website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to add a select language choice on a website made on Bootstrap? It is made in the English language and I was hoping to add select Greek to the site because it is for a church with a lot of people who only speak and read Greek.
[This is the site I am looking to do it for.](http://stnickporticons.com/)

I've been searching and searching and can't find anything.

Comment: Of coarse that you can add a select the problem is how you manage the content in the other language

Comment: would I have to rewrite every page in Greek?

Comment: You could try dynamically loading the content from a text file or xml etc so when a user swaps languages it loads another part of the xml and provide or also maybe look into this https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534601?hl=en-GB for automatic translations. Or translate your site into another language and provide static files as stated before with the translated text however automated translation still seems to be fairly bad at this point.

Comment: that google links looks cool. I don't know why it didn't show up when I was searching google